# How to make custom advancements the only advancements in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've recently added custom advancements to my Minecraft world, but I want to remove the original advancements from the world.

How do I make my custom advancements the only visible ones?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was given on Reddit here: https://www.reddit.com/user/Arcensoth/comments/6ekrk8/minecraft_how_to_remove_vanilla_advancements/

You can overwrite the root advancement of every tab with something hidden that cannot be obtained. That will disable the entire tab.

```
{
 "parent":"some arbitrary example text",
 "criteria":{
  "impossible":{
   "trigger":"minecraft:impossible"
  }
 },
 "display":{
  "hidden":true
 }
}
```

This has to exist as `root.json` in the folders

- `data/advancements/minecraft/adventure`
- `data/advancements/minecraft/end`
- `data/advancements/minecraft/husbandry`
- `data/advancements/minecraft/nether`
- `data/advancements/minecraft/story`

If you also want to disable Vanilla recipes, you can put the same file into `data/advancements/minecraft/recipes`.